# Copiar TextView en Clipboard al ser pulsado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero hacer que cuando mantenga pulsado un TextView en andorid studio se me copie en el portapaples, he intendado poner la linea `android:longClickable="true"` dentro de la etiqueta del text view tal como lei en una pagina, pero nada.

Cambien he visto en la documentación de android y he probado a poner este codigo en el `OnClick` del `TextView`, pero nada, no me da ningún error, pero tampoco se me copia en el portapeles. Seguramente este pondiendolo mal,

¿Alguien me podria decir como hacerlo, bien a modo de etiqueta o a modo de codigo java?

```
   public class FragLay extends Activity {
    TextView textView3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag_lay);
        textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager myClipboard = myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData myClip;
                int min = 0;
                int max = textView3.getText().length();
                if (textView3.isFocused()) {
                    final int selStart = textView3.getSelectionStart();
                    final int selEnd = textView3.getSelectionEnd();
                    min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
                    max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
                    final CharSequence selectedText = textView3.getText().subSequence(min, max);
                    String text = selectedText.toString();
                    myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                    myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Has intentado asignandole el atributo [`android:textIsSelectable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textIsSelectable) sobre el TextView?

Comment: Si, he probado eso y no es lo que quiero, eso lo que hace es que me permite seleccionar el texto para copiarlo, lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando pulse el textview se me copie automaticamente todo el textview en el portapapeles y si es posible lanzar un toast informativo @EinerSantanaR

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte tienes dos problemas, el primero es determinar realizar el copiado de datos al portapapeles si el textview esta enfocado, esto no ocurrira al dar click en el botón, el otro problema es que no estas obteniendo correctamente el Texto, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Intenta que al momento de dar clic, obtienes el texto del `TextView` y lo guardas en el portapeles:

```
textView3.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // obtenemos el texto del textView3
            String text = textView3.getText().toString();
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text",  text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: @EinerSantanaR podrías poner el mismo ejemplo pero para que lo copie al mantener pulsado ? En vez de únicamente pulsar, te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas determinando copiar los datos al portapapeles si el TextView esta siendo enfocado, lo cual no ocurrira con solo dar click, te sugiero eliminar esta parte:

```
  if (textView3.isFocused()) {
```

El otro problema es que no estas obteniendo correctamente el texto dentro del `TextView`, simplemente usa:

```
String text = textView3.getText().toString();
```

este sería el código corregido:

```
    textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ClipboardManager myClipboard = myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData myClip;

                String text = textView3.getText().toString();
                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

            }
        });
```

De esta forma podrás guardar el texto contenido en el `TextView` dentro del portapapeles.